# I am trying to scrape this website, however I keep running into the same error were the script only pastes the parcelID into my google sheets columns

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am very new to coding Started at the beginning of the month.

My brain is cooked, I've been working on this web scraper all weekend and I've hit a dead end. I was able to extract the data I needed from another website but for some reason, this one is tripping me up.

Some key points: script pulls parcel information from cell B, Exports the new data into columns I:U, and iterates through the list of people I have. I'm scraping some data from another site and it's working perfectly this site though is eluding me.

This is my entire patchwork of code please don't bleed too much from your eyes

```
import os
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Define Scopes
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
SPREADSHEET_ID = "MY GOOGLE SHEETS"

# Define Variables for script output
credentials = None
row_counter = None

# Function to authenticate and get credentials
def main():
    global credentials
    credentials = None
    if os.path.exists("token.json"):
        credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(MY DRIVE, SCOPES)
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            with open("token.json", "w") as token:
                token.write(credentials.to_json())

def extract_data_from_website(pid):
    # Construct the URL
    url = f"http://reweb1.co.madison.il.us/parcel/view/0{pid}"

    # Configure Chrome options
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')  # Ignore SSL certificate errors
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    # Install and open Chrome
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    browser.get(url)

    # Wait for the Land_Use_Element to be present
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
    Land_Use_Element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main-column']//div[@class='inner-value'][1]")))
    for Land_Use_Element in Land_Use:
        Land_Use = Land_Use_Element.text
        break
    # Find the remaining div elements with the specified class names
    Property_Classes = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main-column']//div[@class='inner-value'][2]")
    for Property_Class_Element in Property_Classes:
        Property_Class = Property_Class_Element.text
        break
    Tax_Status_Elements = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main-column']//div[@class='inner-value'][3]")
    for Tax_Status_Element in Tax_Status_Elements:
        Tax_Status = Tax_Status_Element.text
        break

    Net_Taxable_Value_Element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main-column']//div[@class='inner-value'][4]")
    for Net_Taxable_Values in Net_Taxable_Value_Element:
        Net_Taxable_Value = Net_Taxable_Values.text
        break

    Total_Tax_Element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main-column']//div[@class='inner-value'][5]")
    for Total_Taxes in Total_Tax_Element:
        Total_Tax = Total_Taxes.text
        break

    Acres_Element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main-column']//div[@class='inner-value'][6]")
    for Acress in Acres_Element:
        Acres = Acress.text
        break

    Last_Sold_Element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main-column']//div[@class='inner-value'][7]")
    for Last_Solds in Last_Sold_Element:
        Last_Sold = Last_Solds.text
        break

    Sale_Price_Element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main-column']//div[@class='inner-value'][8]")
    for Sale_Prices in Sale_Price_Element:
        Sale_Price = Sale_Prices.text
        break

    Permits_Element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main-column']//div[@class='inner-value'][9]")
    for Permitss in Permits_Element:
        Permits = Permitss.text
        break

    Legal_Element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main-column']//div[@class='inner-value'][10]")
    for Legal_Descriptions in Legal_Element:
        Legal_Description = Legal_Descriptions.text
        break

    # Close the browser
    browser.quit()

    # Update the extracted data to the spreadsheet
    range_to_update =f"Cold Information!L{row_counter}:U{row_counter}"
    values_extracted = [Land_Use, Property_Class, Tax_Status, Net_Taxable_Value, Total_Tax, Acres, Last_Sold, Sale_Price, Permits, Legal_Description]
    body = {"values": [values_extracted]}
    
    service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)
    sheets = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheets.values().update(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=range_to_update, valueInputOption="RAW", body=body).execute()

def load_client_information():
    global row_counter
    try:
        service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)
        sheets = service.spreadsheets()

        if row_counter is None:
            row_counter = 2

        # Get the values from column B
        range_values = sheets.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=f"Cold Information!B{row_counter}:B").execute()
        row_values = range_values.get('values', [])

        # Break the loop if there are no more rows with data
        if not row_values:
            print("No more data to process.")
            return

        # Iterate over the retrieved Parcel IDs
        for row in row_values:
            pid = row[0]  # Assuming column B has the Parcel IDs
            extracted_data = extract_data_from_website(pid)

            # Increment row counter for the next iteration
            row_counter += 1

        # Call the function recursively to process the next set of rows
        load_client_information()
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    load_client_information()
```

Here is an example of the element I'm trying to pull data from This is the data im trying to pull (Land_Use, Property_Class, Tax_Status, Net_Taxable_Value, Total_Tax, Acres, Last_Sold, Sale_Price, Permits, Legal_Description)

this is the site as well incase that was not the correct information needed (http://reweb1.co.madison.il.us/parcel/view/062172106101013/2022)

I was able to get the program to iterate the parcel information into all the cols but that was as far as I could figure out.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="inner-label">Parcel Number</div>
                <div class="inner-value">06-2-17-21-06-101-013</div>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="inner-label">Site Address</div>
                    <div class="inner-value">
                        231  S DUNCAN ST<br>
                        MARINE, IL 62061
                    </div>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="inner-label">Owner Name &amp; Address</div>
                    <div class="inner-value" style="white-space:pre-line"> CAPERTON, DAVID AND SHIRLEY
PO BOX 454
MARINE, IL, 62061 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label" style="color:red;">Tax Year</div>
                <div class="inner-value">
                        <div style="display:inline">2022 (Payable 2023)</div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span id="year-dropdown" class="caret"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2023">Tax Year 2023 (Payable 2024)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2022">Tax Year 2022 (Payable 2023)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2021">Tax Year 2021 (Payable 2022)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2020">Tax Year 2020 (Payable 2021)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2019">Tax Year 2019 (Payable 2020)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2018">Tax Year 2018 (Payable 2019)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2017">Tax Year 2017 (Payable 2018)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2016">Tax Year 2016 (Payable 2017)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2015">Tax Year 2015 (Payable 2016)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2014">Tax Year 2014 (Payable 2015)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2013">Tax Year 2013 (Payable 2014)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2012">Tax Year 2012 (Payable 2013)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2011">Tax Year 2011 (Payable 2012)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2010">Tax Year 2010 (Payable 2011)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2009">Tax Year 2009 (Payable 2010)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2008">Tax Year 2008 (Payable 2009)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2007">Tax Year 2007 (Payable 2008)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/parcel/view/062172106101013/2006">Tax Year 2006 (Payable 2007)</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">Sale Status</div>
                <div class="inner-value">
                        <p>None</p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">Neighborhood Code</div>
                <div class="inner-value">
                    <p>0F01 </p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">Land Use</div>
                <div class="inner-value">
                        <p>0431 - Single Family - Residential</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">Property Class</div>
                <div class="inner-value">0040 - IMPROVED LOTS</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">Tax Code</div>
                <div class="inner-value">029 - #2; MARINE VILLG, FIRE &amp; SANITARY</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">Tax Status</div>
                <div class="inner-value">Taxable</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">Net Taxable Value</div>
                <div class="inner-value">43,420</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">Tax Rate</div>
                    <div class="inner-value">8.115500</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="float:right; padding-top:2px;">
                </div>
                <div class="inner-label">Total Tax</div>
                    <div class="inner-value">$3,523.76</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">Township</div>
                <div class="inner-value">06-MARINE</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">Acres</div>
                <div class="inner-value">0.0000</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">Mailing Address</div>
                    <div class="inner-value" style="white-space:pre-line"></div>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                    <td colspan="1">
                        <div class="inner-label">1977 Assessment</div>
                        <div class="inner-value">440</div>
                    </td>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">Lot Size</div>
                <div class="inner-value"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="inner-label">TIF Base Value</div>
                <div class="inner-value">0</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <div class="inner-label">Legal Description</div>
                <div class="inner-value">
                        <p>SPIES &amp; FEIKERTS ADD LTS 15-16 &amp; S 40' LTS 13,14 90 X 200</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
            </tbody></table>
```

this is the error i get when trying to run the script

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58163/devtools/browser/bc005e0f-6ecb-4f87-86a8-400f6daf713e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\asd\Desktop\VSC\Code\Parcelscraper.py", line 149, in <module>
    load_client_information()
  File "c:\Users\asd\Desktop\VSC\Code\Parcelscraper.py", line 137, in load_client_information
    extracted_data = extract_data_from_website(pid)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\asd\Desktop\VSC\Code\Parcelscraper.py", line 55, in extract_data_from_website
    Land_Use_Element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main-column']//div[@class='inner-value'][1]")))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\asd\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008AA813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x0083C4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x00745358]
        (No symbol) [0x007709A5]
        (No symbol) [0x00770B3B]
        (No symbol) [0x0079E232]
        (No symbol) [0x0078A784]
        (No symbol) [0x0079C922]
        (No symbol) [0x0078A536]
        (No symbol) [0x007682DC]
        (No symbol) [0x007693DD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B0AABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B4A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B4456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x009351E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x00845F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x00842328]
        (No symbol) [0x0084240B]
        (No symbol) [0x00834FF7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x754800C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FB7B4E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FB7B1E+238]

PS C:\Users\asd\Desktop\VSC\Code>
```